# C# передача видеопотока

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, видео

Интересует материал по такому вопросу : необходимо написать приложение которое будет захватывать монитор и передавать видео поток по сети, куда либо. Интересует литература/статьи или примеры как можно производить захват рабочей области и последующая передача потока.